Prove $C ∼ P(P(\mathbb{N}))$ when $C$ is defined as the set of all $S$ s.t $(z − m, z + m) ∩ S = ∅ $ for every $z∈\mathbb{Z}$, $m∈\mathbb{R}$
First, I know that there is a very similar question - The cardinality of all sets $A$ such that $\forall \ z\in \mathbb{Z} \ , (z-k,z+k)\ \cap A=\emptyset : 0<k<0.5$ , but here I want to  the verify my soultion and to address my apporach (I tought It might spam the question with my long comment of wrong solution suggestment).
The question :
We define a set $S$ such that $(z − m, z + m) ∩ S = ∅ $
For every $z∈\mathbb{Z}$, $m∈\mathbb{R}$ such that $0 < m < 0.5$
$C$ is defined as the set of all $S$
Prove $C ∼ P(P(\mathbb{N}))$
I'm writing my asnwer becuase I think that my approach is incorrect, and it can assumed that my mistakes are brutal so I apologised for that. I would like to have an idea how to approach it correctly and to help me to find my weaknesses in my understanding.
My answer :
I know that in order to prove $C ∼ P(P(\mathbb{N}))$ , we can define a function which is bijection (of course, we can do it in other ways by defining two functions but I thought it will be the most simple way to approach the question), here I'll define with the $co-domain$ of $P(P(\mathbb{Z}))$ beacause the definition of $S$
Let's define  $f : C \rightarrow P(P(\mathbb{Z}))   \space\space f(S) =$ {I} for every $I ∈ P(\mathbb{Z})$
$f$ is total : For each set in $C$ there is a specific element with same $I$
$f$ is injective : Let $S_1$,$S_2∈C$ s.t $f(S_1) = f(S_2)$ ,hence {$I_1$} = {{$I_2$}} and by definition of equaility of sets $I_1 = I_2$
$f$ is surjective : Let {$I$} $∈P(P(\mathbb{Z}))$ , we define {($z$ - $m$, $z$  + m)} ,it can be seen that {($z$ - $m$, $z$  + $m$)}$∈C$ and $f($z$ - $m$, $z$  + $m$) =$ {$I$}.
Hence, the function is Bijection so $C ∼ P(P(\mathbb{Z}))$ , and since $\mathbb{Z} ∼ \mathbb{N}$ by transitive property $C  ∼ P(P(\mathbb{N}))$

You seem to have missed an important detail, which is that $m<0.5$ is a fixed constant. The way you wrote it, $S$ must exclude $(z-m,z+m)$ for all $m<0.5$, which implies that $S$ can only contain numbers of the form $z+0.5$ with $z\in\Bbb Z$, which implies $C∼P(\Bbb Z)$. Do you understand the problem here? Can you visualize the $S$ requirement on the number line?

As for your proof attempt, your definition of $f$ doesn't make sense. $f(S)$ should depend on $S$. What is $I$? How do you obtain $I$ from a given set $S$?
